# Hash decryption, what algorithm can I use

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I have written hash calculate function:

```
var hash = function (string) {
  var h = 7;
  var i = 0;
  var letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";

  while (i < string.length) {
    h = (h * 37 + letters.indexOf( string[i++] ));
  }

  return h;
};
```

Where `string = "agdpeew"` and result is `664804774844`. But now I don't know how I can decipher hash. So, If my input is `664804774844`, answer will `agdpeew`.

What algorithm can I use for this?

Maybe I can start with the division `664804774844 / 37` but how I can get letter indexes?

Comment: Use the 'modulo' operator, often denoted `%`, to get the remainder modulo 37.  That should give you a number in the range 0..36 (actually, less than that) and you can then use it to index the array `letters`.

Comment: *In general*, it's impossible to turn a hash code back into the value from which it was created, because there are more possible strings than hash codes. *Usually*, when somebody is trying to reverse a hash code, he's trying to use the generated hash as a unique key, and that's a very bad idea. For what purpose are you trying to reverse this hash code?

Comment: @JimMischel a homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For short strings, you can start by expressing the number in base 37 - but why are you trying to do this? Most of the use cases for hash functions don't require you to invert the function, and many hash functions are designed for it to be difficult or impossible to invert the function, except by evaluating on input after input until you find one that produces the hash value you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code written in Swift language, it has both encrypt & decrypt of the hash value

```
var letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";
```

***Hashing / Encrypt***

```
func hash(s:String) -> Int{
    var h = 7 as Int;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.characters.count; i++) {
        // Getting the character at index 
        let s2: Character = s[s.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]; 
        // Getting index of string 'acdegilmnoprstuw'
        let l : Int = letters.startIndex.distanceTo(letters.characters.indexOf(s2)!);  
        h = (h * 37 + l);
    }
    return h;
}
```

***Unhashing / Decrypt***

```
func unhash(hashValue:Int) -> String{
    var h = hashValue
    var unhashedString : String = ""

    while(h > 37){
        unhashedString.append(letters[letters.startIndex.advancedBy(h % 37)])
        h = h / 37
    }
    return String(unhashedString.characters.reverse())
}
```